# sort array while async.map running

Tags: javascript, async.js

Im using async map to execute a function and fetch some stats for every item in the array.

```
async.map(myarray,myfunc,function(err,res) ...
```

Meanwhile, ***myarray*** might get sorted and change indexes by user interaction. How would this fair considering ***myfunc*** is trying to modify the array.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the `myarray` to `async.map()`, it creates a copy of the array synchronously. So, you can modify `myarray` all you want; `async.map()` will simply operate on a copy of the original array and return a new array. Try running the example below:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];

function timesTwo(n, done) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    done(null, n * 2);
  }, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function() {
  array.pop();
  $('#pop').text(array);
}, 1000);

async.map(array, timesTwo, function(err, result) {
  $('#result').text(result);
  $('#original').text(array);
});

});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/1.5.2/async.js"></script>
<p> 0ms: Original array passed to async.map(): <span>1,2,3</span></p>
<p> 1000ms: Pop last item of original array: <span id="pop"></span></p>
<p> 2000ms: Result of async.map(): <span id="result"></span></p>
<p> 2000ms: Original array: <span id="original"></span></p>
```

Comment: perhaps im using async.map in the wrong context. in my case your function timesTwo would try to change the value n. something like n = n*2

Comment: and that change is definitely getting reflected in the original array.

Comment: @JabranSaeed I'm not sure how that could be the case. I've taken a look at the [source code](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/3d1781cbb9a215b30fc03c2135309fe3579e5689/lib/internal/map.js#L10), and it's clear that the callback is called with a new array. Although the array is not a deep copy, so perhaps that is the issue if you are operating on objects (it's not clear from the question what your array contains). Can you please expand on your question to show exactly what you are doing? I think we can solve this, but not without more information.